# Can't replace character "\"

Tags: python, backslash

I've been working on a program that reads out an specific PDF and converts the data to an Excel file. The program itself already works, but while trying to refine some aspects I ran into a problem. What happens is the modules I'm working with read directories with simple slashes dividing each folder, such as:

```
"C:/Users/UserX"
```

While windows directories are divided by backslashes, such as:

```
"C:\Users\UserX"
```

I thought using a simple replace would work just fine:

```
directory.replace("\" ,"/")
```

But whenever I try to run the program, the `\` isn't identified as a string. Instead it pops up as orange in the IDE I'm working with (PyCharm). Is there anyway to remediate this? Or maybe another useful solution?

Comment: \ is used for escaping. if you want to use '\' character, you have to use '\\'.

Comment: Python knows how to handle OS directory differences if you use `Path` objects rather than dealing with strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should work with the `os.path` package here.
`os.getcwd()` gives you the current directory, you can add a subfolder of it via more arguments, and put the `filename` last.

```
import os
path_to_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "childFolder", filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the '\' character is represented by '\\':

`directory.replace("\\" ,"/")`

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding another backslash.

First of all you need to pass "C:\Users\UserX" as a raw string. Use

```
directory=r"C:\Users\UserX"
```

Secondly, suppress the backslash using a second backslash.

```
directory.replace("\\" ,"/")
```

All of this is required as in python the backslash (\) is a special character known as an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
import os
path = "C:\\temp\myFolder\example\\"
newPath = path.replace(os.sep, '/')
print(newPath)
Output:<< C:/temp/myFolder/example/  >>
```